# Change textViews if equal to each other

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

So I just asked a question early about how to change a textview by clicking a button and that worked great!

So now... how would i make it so if that I had 1 textview as a counter and another as a limit, and when the counter reaches the limit, the textview1 would go back to 0 and the limit would increase.

I've tried this:

```
If (textViewCounter==textViewLimit);
textViewCounter.setText(0);
textViewLimit.setText(textViewLimit.getText().toString() + 100);
```

But that doesn't work...
How else could i do it?

**EDIT** My question was just an example. I was going to use that to manipulate into my values. but here's everything: the problem code is at the bottom on btnBattle onClick

```
package com.example.intent_buttontests;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.ColorStateList;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PlayScreen extends Activity {

private int i = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.play_screen);


    String Name = getIntent().getStringExtra("strName");
    TextView textview5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    textview5.setText(Name);
    textview5.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);

    String Race = getIntent().getStringExtra("strRace");
    TextView textViewStrRace = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewStrRace);
    textViewStrRace.setText(Race);

    String Class = getIntent().getStringExtra("strClass");
    TextView textViewStrClass = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewStrClass);
    textViewStrClass.setText(Class);

    String Alliance = getIntent().getStringExtra("strAlliance");
    TextView textViewStrAlliance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewStrAlliance);
    textViewStrAlliance.setText(Alliance);

    Button btnInventory = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btnInventory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Inventory.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

        }
    });

    Button btnEquipment = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btnEquipment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Equipment.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

        }
    });

    Button btnStats = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    btnStats.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Statistics.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

        }
    });

    Button btnShop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    btnShop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Shop.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

        }
    });

    Button btnCrafting = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    btnCrafting.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Crafting.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

        }
    });

    Button btnClassTraining = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    btnClassTraining.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ClassTraining.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

        }
    });

    Button btnBattle = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBattle);
    btnBattle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method
            // Definitions

            Spinner spinnerMonsters = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerMonsters);
            TextView textViewBattleResults = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewBattleResults);
            TextView textViewXPValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewXPValue);
            TextView textViewXpNextLevel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewXpNextLevel);

            // When XP limit is reached, increases by 100 and sets back to 0

            if (textViewXPValue.getText().toString().equals(textViewXpNextLevel.getText().toString())); {
            textViewXPValue.setText("0");
            int newLimit = Integer.parseInt(textViewXpNextLevel.getText().toString()) + 100;
            textViewXpNextLevel.setText(newLimit+"");

            }


            if (spinnerMonsters.getItemAtPosition(0).toString().equals("(0) Training Dummy")); {
            textViewBattleResults.setText("You have killed Training Dummy for 10 experience points!");
            i = i+10;
            textViewXPValue.setText(String.valueOf(i));
            }

        }

    });




}
```

}

Comment: The selected code is the only thing im having a problem with. Im not getting an error. the code is just adding things at the wrong time

Answer (score 2):

instead of just compare the text (Strings) of both textviews,

**Update:**

```
If (textViewCounter.getText().toString().equals(textViewLimit.getText().toString()));
{
 textViewCounter.setText(0);
 int newLimit = Integer.parseInt(textViewLimit.getText().toString()) + 100;
 textViewLimit.setText(newLimit+"");
}
```

Comment: Okay i did that but every time i click the button instead of it adding 100 to the current number, it puts it like this: 100100
It just like, adds it to the end of the string instead of changing it?

Comment: How do i do that...? Sorry im still fairly new at this

Comment: Tried that as well and it will increase textViewCounter by 10 and textViewLimit by 100 every time the button is pressed

Comment: Its because your second if condition in button's click always be true.. So it will always executed.. Just swap both if condition put the first one is second and second one is first..

Comment: okay that doesnt work either because now it doesn't add 10 when clicked but it still adds 100 to the limit anyway...

Answer (score 1):

of course it will not work, you cannot compare directly the content of the textView. what you should do is create a String that will hold the content of the text view.

```
String stextViewCounter = textViewCounter.getText().toString();
String stextViewLimit = textViewLimit.getText().toString();

if(stextViewCounter.equal(stextViewLimit)){
     textViewCounter.setText(0);
     textViewLimit.setText(stextViewLimit + 100);
}
```

unless your using intergers then you have to parse it using parse int

Answer (score 0):

```
If (textViewCounter.getText().toString().equals(textViewLimit.getText().toString()));
{
textViewCounter.setText("");
int n = Integer.parseInt(textViewLimit.getText().toString()) + 100;
textViewLimit.setText("" + n);
}
```

Comment: Ok i did that and now every time i click the button, textViewCounter increases by 10 and textViewLimit increase by 100.? So that didn't work

Comment: i think we need to remove ; at end

Answer (score -1):

try using this

```
If (textViewCounter.getText().toString().equals(textViewLimit.getText().toString()))
textViewCounter.setText(0);
textViewLimit.setText(textViewLimit.getText().toString() + 100);
```

this may help you

Comment: Direct comparison on strings using == doesn't work in Java (it compares the references, not the values), you need to use the .equals method instead.